# Source Attachment does not contain the source for the file XPathImpl.class

Tags: java, xml

I searched and could not find this particular issue discussed. I installed eclipse and selenium, and want a way to work with XML. I found several solutions, but the all seem mostly to use a source file that I don't have? I tried downloading jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar, which I found in an internet search, but perhaps I don't know how to point it to my code. For this code:

```
package automationFramework;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
```

then I try to parse an xml:

```
public static String getElementById(String id) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("somelocation"));
        XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpFactory.newXPath();
        String pwdout = xpath.evaluate("/user[@id='" + id.toUpperCase() + "']/cZAR", doc);
        return pwdout;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

etc. When it tries to evaluate the "xpath.evaluate...." line, it throws a "Source Attachment does not contain the source for the file XPathImpl.class"

Comment: Can you do e.printStackTrace() and post the stack

Comment: How would I do that? I'm using Eclipse build ID 20150219-0600.

Comment: In your code - catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace()}

Comment: It never actually gets into the error handling section. More info from the Class File Handler, that shows the error.

// Compiled from XPathImpl.java (version 1.3 : 47.0, super bit)
public class org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl implements javax.xml.xpath.XPath {
  // Field descriptor #88 Ljavax/xml/xpath/XPathVariableResolver;
  private javax.xml.xpath.XPathVariableResolver variableResolver;
  // Field descriptor #90 Ljavax/xml/xpath/XPathFunctionResolver;
  private javax.xml.xpath.XPathFunctionResolver functionResolver;
There are several more field descriptors that also show output.

Comment: It looks like I didn't have the correct source file. I redownloaded xalan-2.7.2 and pointed the jar source to this zip file. Did the same sort of thing with a similar error to the selenium-java-2.46.0.jar file also. That seemed to work.